# Create A Shadow(or blur) when user Click on UIbutton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a One Uibutton in Buttom. when User click on that button a uiview animation is display like popup from buttom to up.
this is my code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame = CGRectMake(self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.origin.x, 1000, self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.width,self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.height);    
}

- (IBAction)animated:(id)sender
{
    if(_isAnimated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame = CGRectMake(self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.origin.x, 520, self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.width,self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
       _isAnimated=NO;  
    }
    else
    {   
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame = CGRectMake(self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.origin.x, 1000, self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.width,self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
                     {

       }];
      _isAnimated=YES;
    }
}
```

Uiview animation is perfectly working but when uiview appear than background view is create shadow(or blur)like uiactionsheet and after finished animation background view is clear.
i dont know how to implemented.
plz help me
i am new in ios...

Comment: Instead you can use two images selected and normal and change accordingly , if no animation required

Comment: thank you for your suggestion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `UIView` in background and set its `backgroundcolor` black and `alpha` 0.5 in storyboard. Then change its `alpha` from 0.5 to 0 with animation. You can also add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detect taps on it and dissmiss the view when user taps outside.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame = CGRectMake(self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.origin.x, 1000,     self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.width,self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.height);    
}

- (IBAction)animated:(id)sender
{
    if(_isAnimated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame = CGRectMake(self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.origin.x, 520, self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.width,self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.height);
                     //showing background view here
                     self.viewBackground.alpha = 0.5;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
        _isAnimated=NO;  
    }    
    else
    {   
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame = CGRectMake(self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.origin.x, 1000, self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.width,self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.height);
                     //dismissing background view here
                     self.viewBackground.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                 {

                 }];
         _isAnimated=YES;
    }
}
```

For detecting taps outside and dismissing your view:

Create a `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture;
}
```

Initialize it in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    //defining your gesture method
    tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapGesture:)];

    //adding gesture recognizer on the background view
    [self.backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}
```

In your Gesture Recognizer Method:

```
-(void)handleSingleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
             animations:^{
                 //dismissing background view here
                 self.viewBackground.alpha = 0.0;
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
             }];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add your code in viewdidload.add QuartzCore framework

```
#import <QuartzCore/CAAnimation.h>

self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame = CGRectMake(self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.origin.x, 1000, self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.width,self.BuyButtonPopUpView.frame.size.height);
CABasicAnimation *animate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
animate.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.5];
animate.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
animate.duration = 1.0;
[self.BuyButtonPopUpView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shadowOpacity"];
self.BuyButtonPopUpView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a UIVisualEffectView first then add the popup over this view.

here is a tutorial link https://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial